# CPU is maxed when running a while loop inside a Long Running task

Tags: c#, loops, task, task-parallel-library, ibm-mq

I am running a constant poll to a messaging server. When a message arrives on the server I grab the message and process it. Unfortunately this is using 80-100% CPU for a simple task. **UPDATE:I have reduced it to the while loop itself.** The while loop inside 10 tasks are causing the CPU to max out at 100% easy.

```
    int i = 0;
    while(true){
     //At the start of every minute
       if (DateTime.Now.Seconds == 0)
      {
        i++;
      }
    }
```

Is there a way that I can throttle the loop or better yet a better way that I can write this code so that it does not use 100% CPU? I have tried to add a Task.Delay of 1 second but that doesn't help much at all.

Any help or advice you can provide I would greatly appreciate it.

```
// First I poll 10 different locations for messages and each task polls its own queue
foreach(Queue queue in queueList)
{
task.Add(Task.Run(() => PollIndividualQueue(queue));
}

t= Task.WhenAll(task.ToArray()).WithAggregatedExceptions();
t.Wait();

//Then in the PollIndividualQueue method I implement the while loop that constantly polls a message queue for the next hour
private async Task<string> PollIndividualQueue(Queue queue)
{
    var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(Timespan.FromMinutes(60)).Token;

  while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
       //Poll the queue and if there is a message grab it and process it
       if(!await GetMessage())
        {
           //I call a stored procedure that inserts this message into the database.
         using(var conn = new SqlConnection(...)
        {
           using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(MyStoredProc, conn)
               {
                cmd.CommandType = Command.StoredProcedure;
                  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQlParameter(...InputMessage));
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
             }
            }
            }
        else
        {
          await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
   }

}

private Task<bool> getMessage(Queue queue)
  {
   object myLock = new object();

   
      try
      {
        Monitor.Enter(myLock);
        queue.Get(message);
      }
      catch(MQException ex)
      {
       if(ex.ReasonCode == 2033)
       {
         return false;
       }
      }
     finally
     {
       Monitor.Exit(myLock);
     }    
}
```

**EDIT: Thank you all for the comments but it seems to be getting off track to the actual question. The question is there a way to use a percentage of the total CPU?
I can literally take all of this code out of the While loop and the CPU is still at 100%. The while loop is what is driving the CPU load it seems.**

Comment: Why are you doing `Task.Run`?  Just do `task.Add(PollIndividualQueue(queue));`  And why isn't `GetMessage` async?  And is any of the stuff in the `if` async or is it just CPU intensive code?  And you really should use `await` instead of `Wait()`.

Comment: What does `GetMessage()` look like? Does it block? Is it a busy task that loops until a message is available?

Comment: Hi @Corey I added more detail. It doesn't block it basically queues the queue looking for a message. It takes milliseconds to return a value;

Comment: your getMessage has issues, it uses a local lock variable and there is no corresponding exit call.

Comment: Hi @ScottyD0nt I forgot to add the finally block that has the exit call. So you are saying I should not be using a local lock variable? Since I am using the message across multiple tasks would that cause a race condition if I make it on a class level?

Comment: There's no point locking a local variable. You're never going to compete with another thread.

Comment: If you're not going to post actual code, or at least a minimum repro, then how are we supposed to help you? I could make some random guesses if you like, but they're unlikely to be useful. Or you could post the rest of the `getMessage` method, which is probably where the issue lies.

Comment: I would suggest you use the IBM MQ XMS.NET API which does implement a async listener.   If you want to do it the way you currently are then add a receiver timeout to your get,  this will wait up to that amount of time for a message to hit the queue before returning 2033 but will return as soon as a message is available.

Comment: @CodeMan03 `It doesn't block` actually it does. That `Monitor` is used to lock and therefore block. You could have used just `lock(myLock)` as `lock` uses a `Monitor` under the hood. Thread switching is expensive so .NET tries to prevent this by using a spinwait at first before putting the thread to sleep. That means a core will be at 100% for a while. And since you work on a threadpool thread, locking ends up putting stealing a thread from the threadpool

Comment: @JoshMc thanks for that tip I will look into that. Also normally we have maybe thousands of messages constantly arriving in the queue during work hours. So the CPU is maxed during that time as it is constantly looping because messages exist. Is there a way to reduce the CPU usage in the loop?

Comment: @CodeMan03 `it seems to be getting off track to the actual question.` no, you still haven't posted the code that's relevant to the question. There's nothing wrong with tasks. The code you posted *does* block and *does* cause 100% core usage when it does this. So does the loop you posted. If you execute 4 such loops in a quad-core machine, you'll end up with 100% CPU usage. There's no need for this or such complex code though. For starters, what is `Queue`? A queue client? A .NET Queue class? You could use a `Channel` to avoid locking *and* blocking

Comment: @CodeMan03 perhaps you should describe the *actual* problem, not how you think it should be solved. You are receiving messages from a Something and storing them to the database. What is that Something? There *are* ways to work without any locks or polling loops

Comment: If your EDIT is telling us to ignore most of what you have written in the question, perhaps instead just delete the parts of the question that are not what you want to talk about. Do you literally just want to ask about why an empty while loop causes 100% CPU?

Comment: Your code is basically  
while(true){
           x =DateTime.Now.Seconds 
    }
You need to put a wait in it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok.  Clearly, you are a newbie, so I'll attempt to be kind with my comments.

1. Your while loop at the top of your questions is extremely bad programming.  You wonder why it is maxing out your CPU?  If you are running on an Intel i9-9900K then that loop will be executed many billions of times per ***second***.  I'm not kidding!!
2. If you want to do something once a second then you need to do a simple time calculation then sleep.  To quiet the CPU down, your code should be:

   > ```
   > int i = 0;
   > while (true) {
   >    //At the start of every minute
   >    Thread.Sleep((int)(60000 - ((DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond) % 60000)));
   >    i++;
   > }
   > ```
3. I really don't understand you are using locks in the getMessage method.  The Queue's Get method blocks when it attempts to retrieve a message.
4. If you are going to use threading then why don't you have each thread separately connect to the queue manager as there is no reason to share a connection between threads.

Comment: no, it won't run 53 billion times per second but still in the range of billions per second and consume 100% of that CPU core. It's the worst way to check for time. The correct solution is to use a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0) which results in more correct time than sleeping

Comment: Intel says that i9-9900K CPU will do 53.429 billion instructions per second, so I'll split the difference with you. :)

Comment: where did you get that number? And no, **that loop isn't a single instruction** but at least some method calls to get the datetime value, a comparison and a jump. Remember system calls are very slow, and C# calls are also slow and even slower when marshalling to native functions like system calls. So I expect that you need to divide the number by at least 10 to get the number of times the loop run in a second

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes in this answer. Thread switching is a very expensive operation, which means that `Thread.Sleep` will harm performance. If that is called inside a task, MVC action or anything else that uses a threadpoll thread, that `Sleep` will remove it from use.  That's why timers or `await Task.Delay()` are used.

Comment: As for sharing queue connections, one can't just assume how expensive a connection is or whether it's thread-safe or not. HttpClient for example is thread-safe and meant to be reused because *connections at the TCP level* are expensive. Database connections aren't thread-safe, they are expensive, but connection pooling makes reopening them cheap.

Comment: @phuclv I can't find the original page that had 53 billion but wiki has I9-9900K CPU listed at 420 billion instructions per second: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second Also the loop had 2 instructions & the 3rd was only executed some of the time.  Hence, many billions of instructions will be executed per second.

Comment: @Roger you're wrong. `DateTime.Now.Seconds` are several function calls because date in second isn't available for you anywhere in any registers and you must call a system call to get it. I didn't even say anything about the loop body previously because it's very rarely run, so for most of the loops only the function calls, compare and conditional jump are executed. The increment in the body would be rarely touched

Comment: @Roger And you don't understand MIPS at all, and are just too naive to take that number without a grain of salt. It's the value for multiple cores and when pipelining along with OoO and SIMD are used. Indeed each [OoO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution) CPU core can run multiple instructions at the same time, but only when there are independent data that can be calculated in parallel. What else do you calculate in each loop apart from getting time and comparing it with zero? So you can never achieve the maximum throughput for this loop

Comment: @phuclv  I said "many billions of instructions" (in the comments), I did not say it would do 420 BIPS.  And you even said, "still in the range of billions per second".  Also, I have probably written more Assembly and low-level C code than you will ever write.  Many, many moons ago, I wrote an entire text editor in 8086 Assembly (by myself).  So, I would take it down a notch as I was not taking a shot at you or questioning your math/calculations.